# Lombok: Cannot see getters and setters in Eclipse IDE (with Ctrl-Space)

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I have this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

and this class:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SomeClass {

    private String someField1;
    private String someField2;
```

Then from another class, I do:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
```

Now, when I enter in EclipseIDE, `someClass.` and press Ctrl-Space, I dont see the Getters and Setters.
Is it how Lombok is supposed to work? For me, thats the main use case. I want to have Ctrl-Space with my Getters and Setters.

Comment: Did you install lombok jar in your ide? You will need to install it at first place.

Comment: Adding to Aniket's comment... instructions are here: https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You would need to Download jar from https://projectlombok.org/download or use the jar which is downloaded from your maven build.

**In case of windows follow below steps to use Lombok in your project.**

> 1.Execute command in terminal: java -jar lombok.jar
>
> 2.This command will open window, install and quit the installer and restart eclipse.

**If you are on MacOS, then follow below steps to use Lombok in your project.**

> 1.Copy lombok.jar into Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS directory.
>
> 2.Add -javaagent:lombok.jar to the end of Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini file.
>
> 3.Restart Eclipse and enable “Annotation Processing” in project properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the lombok plugin into you eclipse:

- Download jar from https://projectlombok.org/
- Copy the lombok.jar into the root Eclipse folder and run the below command

> java -jar lombok-1.18.12.jar

- This will open a small UI, where the location of
  the Eclipse installation can be specified.
- Usually the Eclipse
  installation will be found automatically and lombok can be installed
  or updated. Just press the Install / Update button and restart the
  IDE

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add it to the plugins to get that out in Eclipse. Sharing a link which will be helpful for your setup,

[Setting up Lombok with Eclipse and Intellij](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide)